# The initial sigma-algebra on the dual of a Banach lattice

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, measurable-functions, banach-lattices

Let $E$ be an AL space (i.e. a Banach lattice whose norm is additive on the positive cone $E_+$) that satisfies Mazur's condition (every sequentially weak$^*$-continuous functional on $E'$ is weak$^*$-continuous). Define the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ on $E$ as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that each $\phi\in V$ is measurable, where $V$ is a weak$^*$-dense subspace of $E'$. Can one show that each $\psi\in E'$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable?

Alternatively, we could take $V$ to be a weak$^*$-dense subspace of the order-continuous dual $E_n^\tilde{}$ and define $\mathcal{F}$ as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ such that each $\phi\in V$ is measurable. In that case, can one show that each $\psi\in E_n^\tilde{}$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable?

Comment: If you have two unescaped occurrences of `*` in the same paragraph (and some other regex-ical conditions), then they will be taken as *emphasis* (in a post, but apparently not in a comment, so I can't demonstrate).  You can fix this by escaping them, like `weak\*`, or by setting them in TeX, as `weak$^*$`.  Since you did the latter once, I edited to do it consistently, but this has the drawback that a linebreak is allowed between `weak` and `$^*$` (and, indeed, this happens for me here). If you prefer `\*` (no linebreak), please make sure to do it consistently to avoid accidental emphasis.